# References on Kähler Differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I'm working on an independent study project on Kähler differentials for my commutative algebra class. I'm looking for any references on these that might help me out. Any references to their use in algebraic geometry could also be of help.

Comment: Vakil has a wonderful chapter on this in his "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry", namely Chapter 21. The stacks project also has a nice section on differentials, which can be found here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM.

Comment: I remember Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory as a good reference for these things.

Comment: By far the best references I am familiar with are Matsamura (both his Commutative Ring Theory and Commutative algebra books) and Eisenbud's Commuative Algebra with a View Towards Algebraic Geometry. These are the only standard references I know that are relatively complete for a beginner. In general it seems like there is a gap in the introductory literature on this material.

Comment: I would also take a look at the first chapter of Sernesi's Deformations of Algebraic Schemes. It doesn't cover any more content than the above recommendations, but it does so more precisely. It includes details and subtleties that I find are skipped over in some more introductory texts.